# Run time error when running very simple program (C++)

Tags: c++, vector, stl, runtime-error

I wrote a program as part of a learning exercise that takes doubles as inputs, and outputs the total sum of all the doubles, as well as the smallest, largest, and the mean. When trying to run the program, I get this run time error:

```
 Unhandled exception at 0x74b01d4d in Hello World.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Range_error at memory location 0x00dcf760.
```

When I use the Visual Studio 2010 debug option, I get `vector subscript is out of range`.

The code is:

```
#include "C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\std_lib_facilities.h"

int main() {
    vector<double> v;
    double number = 0;
    cout << "Enter the distance between two cities along the route.\n";
    while (cin >> number) {
        double sum = 0;
        v.push_back(number);
        sort(v.begin(),v.end());
        for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
            sum += v[i];
        cout << "The total distance from each city is " << sum 
                     << ". The smallest distance is " << v[0] 
                     << " and the greatest distance is " << v[v.size()] 
                     <<". The mean distance is " << sum/v.size() <<".\n";
        cout << "Enter the distance between two cities along the route.\n";}
}
```

I had to change the type of the variable defined in the `for` loop because I was getting a signed/unsigned mismatch error. The code gives no errors when compiled and I am having difficulty seeing the problem.

Comment: the debugger would have told you this if you'd asked. Choose Break when it blows up and you'll see the problem line. Hover over each variable in the line and you'll see that there is one entry in the vector, v[0], but size is 1, which is why v[i] is out of range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
" and the greatest distance is " << v[v.size()]
```

is an undefined behavior because the last index in vector is `v.size() - 1` if `v.size() > 0` (if v.size() = 0 there is no items and nothing to subscript)

You should thus write:

```
if( !v.empty())
    std::cout << " and the greatest distance is " << v[ v.size() - 1];
```

or better;

```
if ( !v.empty()) {
    std::cout << " and the greatest distance is " << v.back();
```

[std::vector::back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back)